# How to access MongoDB array in which is are stored key-value pairs by key name

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I am working with pymongo and after writing aggregate query

`db.collection.aggregate([{'$project': {'Id': '$ResultData.Id','data' : '$Results.Data'}}])`

I received the object:

```js
{'data': [{'key': 'valid', 'value': 'true'},
      {'key': 'number', 'value': '543543'},
      {'key': 'name', 'value': 'Saturdays cx'},
      {'key': 'message', 'value': 'it is valid.'},
      {'key': 'city', 'value': 'London'},
      {'key': 'street', 'value': 'Bigeye'},
      {'key': 'pc', 'value': '3566'}],
```

Is there a way that I can access the values by the key name? Like that `'$Results.Data.city'` and I will receive London. I would like to do that on the level of MongoDB aggregate query so it means I want to write a query in the way:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{'$project': 
    {'Id': '$ResultData.Id',
    'data' : '$Results.Data',
    'city' : $Results.Data.city',
    'name' : $Results.Data.name',
    'street' : $Results.Data.street',
    'pc' : $Results.Data.pc',
            }}])
```

And receive all the values of provided keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html)  *projection* operator in the following query from *mongo shell*:

```
db.collection.find(
  { _id: <some_value> }, 
  { _id: 0, data: { $elemMatch: { key: "city" } } } 
)
```

The output:

```
{ "data" : [ { "key" : "city", "value" : "London" } ] }
```

Using *PyMongo* (gets the same output):

```
collection.find_one( 
  { '_id': <some_value> }, 
  { '_id': 0, 'data': { '$elemMatch': { 'key': 'city' } } } 
)
```

Using *PyMongo* ***aggregate*** method (gets the same result):

```
pipeline = [
  {
      '$project': {
         '_id': 0,
          'data': {
              '$filter': {
                  'input': '$data', 'as': 'dat',
                  'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$dat.key', INPUT_KEY ] }
              }
          }
      }
  }
]

INPUT_KEY = 'city'

pprint.pprint(list(collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Naming the received object "`result`", if `result['data']` always is a list of dictionaries with 2 keys (`key` and `value`), you can convert the whole list to a dictionary using `key`s as keys and `value`s as values. Given that this statement is somewhat confusing, here's the code:

```
data = {pair['key']: pair['value'] for pair in result['data']}
```

From here, `data['city']` will give you `'London'`, `data['street']` will be `'Bigeye'` and so on. Obviously, this assumes that there are no conflicts amoung `key` values in `result['data']`. Note that this dictionary will (just as the original `result['data']`) only contain strings so don't expect `data['number']` to be an integer.

Another approach would be to dynamically create an object holding each key-value pair as an attribute, allowing you to use the following syntax: `data.city`, `data.street`, ... But this would required more complicated code and is a less common and stable approach.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I would like to do this on the level of MongoDB aggregate query.